# Bootstrap: how to Make the website always operate as "lg"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a fully responsive website with the classes `hidden-*`, `visible-*` are being used extensively, now i want to let the mobile users to be able to use the desktop version of the website if they click on a button like "Desktop Website".

**These are Bootstrap documentations for `Disabling Responsiveness`:**

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs.
2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a
   single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this
   comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
   !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding
   behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place
   of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid
   scales to all resolutions.

I tried it but it's not working!.

The `Media Queries` still operational.

The `hidden-*` and `visible-*` still operational.

So nothing happened, the `responsiveness` still operational!.

I don't know why it's a difficult thing to do. The website is already configured to run on desktop devices, so i just need to tell the `Mobile` or `Tablet` to browse the website like a `Desktop` does. Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you throw an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something? I also don't see you mentioning : `Disable the responsiveness of Bootstrap by fixing the width of the container and using the first grid system tier.` Are you also doing this?

Comment: @Invent-Animate Yes i made.container{ width: 1100px; }, but how can i use only the first grid system tier ?

the website has all 4 tiers `xs`, `sm`, `md`, and `lg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best approach for you would be to compile a separate version of Boostrap without any of its responsive goodies. Check this [blog](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-twitters-bootstrap-3-without-responsive-features/) entry on how to do that. Let me know if that helped/worked. 
Fabio

Comment: It didn't work, the website is already done, i just want to apply the `Desktop View` for mobile devices, i can't go and alter the whole website, it'll take so much time.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly how your CSS is set up, I suggest you look at [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) as part of the documentation.

Here is how some of the non-responsive CSS works in that example..

```
/* Non-responsive overrides
 *
 * Utilize the following CSS to disable the responsive-ness of the container,
 * grid system, and navbar.
 */

/* Reset the container */
.container {
  width: 970px;
  max-width: none !important;
}

/* Demonstrate the grids */
.col-xs-4 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

.container .navbar-header,
.container .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

/* Always float the navbar header */
.navbar-header {
  float: left;
}

/* Undo the collapsing navbar */
.navbar-collapse {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

/* Always apply the floated nav */
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 15px;
}

/* Redeclare since we override the float above */
.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

/* Undo custom dropdowns */
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #333;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #428bca !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

/* Undo form expansion */
.navbar-form {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

/* Copy-pasted from forms.less since we mixin the .form-inline styles. */
.navbar-form .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .form-control-static {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-form .input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
.navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-form .input-group > .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-form .control-label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .radio,
.navbar-form .checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .radio label,
.navbar-form .checkbox label {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
.navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  top: 0;
}
```

If you're asking how to always use `.col-xs*`, this is defined on your element's class. Unless you want to write a script to replace every `.col-*` with a `.col-xs`, you'll have to change these manually.

Comment: Actually i want to always use `col-lg-*` and ignore the `col-xs-*`, i'll look at your code.

Comment: You **need** to use `col-xs` in conjunction with/in lieu of `col-lg`

Comment: The problem is that i have so many different classes that uses the `Responsiveness` capabilities of Bootstrap like : `hidden-*`, `visible-*` and the `col-*-*`, it's so difficult to deal with all that classes.

Comment: Trust me, I agree. It sounds like there were bad requirements or something. This could be a *lot* of rework depending on the scope of your project/app. It kind of sucks.

Comment: Okay.... I would follow the documentation, especially if you plan to upgrade to a later version of Bootstrap down the road.